# Generate hi resolution pdf on ios

Tags: ios, pdf, retina-display

Is there any way to generate high resolution PDFs on ios that support retina display? I made a basic PDF generator but on my iPad 3 it still looks pixelated. Thank you for all kind of advices!

**Update:**

In my PDF file text are smooth and beautiful. But when I use code to draw this pdf i got pixelated on retina display (drawing code is in a bottom).

PDF generation:

```
    NSString *fileName = [self.bookManager cacheBookFileForPage:i];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(fileName, CGRectZero, nil);

    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, 100);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

    // TODO: Temporary numbers
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 768 * 2, 1024 * 2), nil);


    NSString *textToDraw = @"text";
    CFStringRef stringRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)textToDraw;

    CTFontRef ctFont= CTFontCreateWithName(CFSTR("Arial"), 20 * 2, &CGAffineTransformIdentity);

    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                (__bridge id)ctFont, (NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                nil];

    NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textToDraw
                                                                 attributes:attributes];

    CFRelease(ctFont);


    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)string);

    // TODO: temporary        
    CGRect frameRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 800 * 2, 50 * 2);
    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

    // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
    CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);

    // Draw the frame.
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CFRelease(stringRef);
    CFRelease(framesetter);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

PDF Drawing:

```
// This will return pageRef from PDF
CGPDFPageRef page = [self.bookManager contentForPage:index + 1];

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context));
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, [self.view.layer bounds].size.height);

CGRect transformRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, [self.view.layer bounds].size.width, [self.view.layer bounds].size.height);
CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, transformRect, 0, true);

// And apply the transform.
CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);

CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);

CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
```

Comment: What kind of content do you have in your document? If your images contain jaggies, then you need to increase their resolution. If your fonts are pixelated, then perhaps you're not using a vector-based font - what fonts are you using? How did you generate your PDF?

Comment: @halfer you are right. This question require some code :)

Comment: A much better question. OK, if you view the generated PDF on a desktop machine, do you get the jagged fonts at a high zoom level? If not, then the problem is in your display code. (Not an iOS programmer, but now you have code in your question, someone can help you).

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the problems you have is that you are scaling what you are drawing; don't use that transform! Just create your pdf context and draw natively in that. Your fonts will look crisp as they are now drawn in full resolution, instead of half rez and then the bitmap of that  font is scaled up, which of course introduces jaggies.

tl;dr: draw directly to the pdf, don't use the scaling transform on text.